# Transition Probabilities in Discrete Time Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, conditional-probability

If someone would be able to point me in a starting direction, I would be greatly appreciative.

**Question**

I am attempting to derive a closed form for the transition probabilities of the discrete time Markov Chain $(X_n, n\in\mathbb{N})$ in a infection/recovery type process.

> Where,
>
> - $Y_n$ : Number of newly infected during the $n^{th}$ period
> - $X_n$ : Total number of infected at the start of $n^{th}$ period
> - $c\in(0,1)$   : Infection rate
> - $r\in(0,1)$   : Recovery rate
> - $N\in\mathbb{N}$ : Total Population
>
> And,
>
> $${\left({Y}_{{n}}∣{X}_{{n}}\right)} \sim {Bin}{\left({N}-{X}_{{n}}, 
> {c}\right)},∀{n}∈{\mathbb{N}}$$
>
> $${\left({X}_{{{n}+{1}}}∣{X}_{{n}},{Y}_{{n}}\right)}\sim {Bin}{\left({X}_{{n}}+{Y}_{{n}},{\left({1}-{r}\right)}\right)},  \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

**My attempt**

My initial approach was simply to apply the Law of Total Probability

$$
\\\mathbb{P}{\left({X}_{{{n}+{1}}}={j}∣{X}_{{n}}={i}\right)}={∑_{{{k}={0}}}^{{{N}-{i}}}}\mathbb{P}{\left({X}_{{{n}+{1}}}={j}∣{X}_{{n}}={i},{Y}_{{n}}={k}\right)}\mathbb{P}{\left({Y}_{{n}}={k}∣{X}_{{n}}={i}\right)}
\\=\sum _{k=0}^{N-i}\binom{i+k}{j}(1-r)^jr^{i+k-j}\binom{N-i}{k}c^k(1-c)^{N-i-k}
\\=\left(\frac{1-r}{r}\right)^j r^i(1-c)^{N-i}\sum _{k=0}^{N-i}\binom{i+k}{j}\binom{N-i}{k}\left(r\times\frac{c}{1-c}\right)^k
$$
I then attempted to expand the combinations in terms of their factorial definition, but that didn't yield a closed form solution as far as I could tell.

Not really sure where to go from here. Not sure if I've made a mistake in my approach or if there is some step that will help this summation cancel. I would really appreciate if someone could point out any mistakes I have made and/or give me some guidance in regards to an approach.

Comment: You can simplify things a bit by skipping the people who recover right after infection:

\begin{eqnarray*}
A_n&\sim&\operatorname{Bin}(N-X_n,c(1-r))\;,\\
B_n&\sim&\operatorname{Bin}(X_n,1-r)\;,\\
X_{n+1}&=&A_n+B_n\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

But then you'll still have a hypergeometric sum for the transition probabilities that I doubt you can simplify.